# Powershell 2.0 Remoting loading a .Net 4.0 dll

Tags: powershell, .net-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to load a .Net 4.0 assembly, using [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom, inside of a remote Powershell 2.0 session. It works locally, due to a change I made to the powershell.exe.config file, but fails with a "This assembly is built by a runtime newer ..." exception in a remote session.

Both machines involved have .Net 2.0 and 4.0, and have the powershell.exe.config change for the x86 and x64 bit powershell executables. I've also tried changing the server powershell registry keys:
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Powershell\1\PowerShellEngine\RuntimeVersion
HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Powershell\1\PowerShellEngine\RuntimeVersion

I must be missing something, but I don't know what it is.

**Edit:**
Following is an example of the code I am executing.

```
PS C:\>Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server1
[server1]: PS C:\stuff> dir *.dll | foreach { [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( $_.FullName ) }
```

Comment: Please show the command you're using..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to create a c:\windows\System32\wsmprovhost.exe.config file and a c:\windows\SysWOW64\wsmprovhost.exe.config file, **on the server**, similar to the one I found at: http://poshcode.com/2045

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I found the following article, which hinted at wsmprovhost.exe needing to be configured just like the powershell.exe file.
http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-later-versions-of-net-framework.html