# Serialized xml is nested too deeply

Tags: xml, powershell, .net-4.0, config, powershell-remoting

I tried to fix [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110746/powershell-same-input-command-but-different-outputs-depending-on-remote-loc)

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631710/powershell-2-0-remoting-loading-a-net-4-0-dll) leading me to [this](http://tfl09.blogspot.fr/2010/08/using-later-versions-of-net-framework.html)

Not only it didn't fix the initial problem, but I am now unable to remote query
a SQL Server (I am not even sure this is the reason, but it worked before).
I may have screwed something up.

Here is the Powershell command and the output (it used to work) :

```
PS C:\Users\lh\powershell\> invoke-command -ComputerName $ip -Credential $cred {invoke-sqlcmd -query "select @@version"}

Les données XML sérialisées sont imbriquées trop profondément. (= "Serialized xml is nested too deeply")
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (1.2.3.4:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : 1.2.3.4
```

This error (wich I dont understand) seems to have a lot of possible causes. 
Note that it works if I run it locally using RDP :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> invoke-sqlcmd -query $sql
<rows>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a problem very similar, in fact it was the "Second Hop" problem. After enabling credssp as detailed in the link below, the issue was fixed.

[Enable PowerShell "Second-Hop" Functionality with CredSSP](http://i1.blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx)